# Apex, SOQL, add results from database to the List, error

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I would like to add results from database to the List. But there is a bug.

```
String str = '\'AOC\',\'BPD\',\'CRE\'';
List<String> lstString = str.split(',');
List<Shop_Product__c> productList = new List<Shop_Product__c>();
Integer i = 0;
for (String record: lstString) {
    System.debug('record[' + i + ']: ' + record);
    if ((record != null) && (productList != null)) {
      productList.add([SELECT Id, Brand__c 
                       FROM Shop_Product__c 
                       WHERE Brand__c = :record
                       LIMIT 10]);
      
      System.debug('productList[' + i + ']: ' + productList);
      System.debug('Here in for ----------------------------------------');
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Error is **System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**.
[Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215950/fatal-errorsystem-queryexception-list-has-no-rows-for-assignment-to-sobject) is it the explain, but I don't understand what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` method `add()` takes a single sObject. That's why you get the `QueryException`, just like in the examples you link to.

You can use the `addAll()` method to create a `List<sObject>` context, which avoids the exception if there are no responsive records.

Comment: With the addAll() method it is without error. Thanks.